# Yocto Morty: too spread python package dependencies

Tags: python-2.7, dependencies, embedded-linux, yocto, openembedded

Does anybody know what has been changed in python recipes dependencies in Yocto Morty?

I'm trying to build small Linux image (< 100 MB, but smaller is better) containing *python-core*, *python-django* and some other modules. I have listed those packages in *IMAGE_INSTALL_append* in image recipe and in Yocto **Krogoth** I got what I wanted. I used the same image recipe in Yocto **Morty** and the image is much more bigger!

Image built by Morty contains not wanted packages like *python-distutils*, *python-2to3*... I think some new, too spread dependencies were introduced causing all *python-modules* package brought into image.

I have set NO_RECOMMENDATIONS = "1" in conf/local.conf but it does not help.

When I set for example PACKAGE_EXCLUDE = " python-2to3" then I get error:

```
Computing transaction...error: Can't install python-modules-2.7.12r1@armv7a_neon: unable to install provider for python-2to3:
error:     python-2to3-2.7.12-r1@armv7a_neon is to be excluded
```

I'm thinking about manual removal of files using ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND, but I'd like really to avoid that as too brutal and hard to mantain option.

Any ideas how to get only required single python packages in Morty?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Something in your image recipe is obviously asking for those packages. Maybe a packagegroup you use contains python-modules? Hard to tell without your recipe.

Comment: Also note that Yocto/oe-core is moving to python3 as default: if you keep using python2 that means you may end up with both pythons on the image (this happens with current master, not 100% sure about Morty).

Comment: @jku I used exactly the same image recipe which was used in Krogoth. In Krogoth python-modules were not included, but in Morty there were automagically brought to image.

Comment: Of course things can change between versions, that's kind of the point (but no, magic is not involved: something is dragging python-modules into your image). If you don't share any details of your image then it's hard for anyone to help.